# Check UAC status

Tags: batch-file, uac

How to script a batch file that would run a check whether or not UAC is enabled by:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA
```

It is enabled if the result is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    **0x1**)
```

and it is disabled if the result is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System EnableLUA    REG_DWORD    **0x0**)
```

The script should then run different commands according to the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply search for one or the other value with either `FIND` or `FINDSTR` and invoke commands depending on the result of the search. The pattern would basically be like this:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA | (
  FIND "0x1" >NUL
) && (
  command(s)_to_run_when_UAC_is_enabled
) || (
  command(s)_to_run_when_UAC_is_disabled
)
```

I.e. the `REG` produces an output which is passed, using the "pipe" (`|`) to the input of `FIND`. `FIND` looks for `0x1` in its input, and, depending on the result of the search, one of the following bracketed blocks of commands is executed.

The `command && command || command` is a standard mechanism that allows you to selectively run commands, a kind of replacement for `IF`. The first command produces a result. The command just after `&&` runs if the result is "success", and the command just after `||` runs in case of a fail.

If you need to perform actions in both cases, use both `&&` and `||` after the command generating the result, but if only one kind of result should be reacted to, you can leave out either `&&` or `||`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough description! I tried executing this but it didn't seem to work for me. For example I tried:

`REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA | (
  FIND "0x1" >NUL
) && (
  shutdown -t 0 -r -f  
) || (
  command(s)_to_run_when_UAC_is_disabled
)`

My UAC is enabled but my PC didn't shutdown, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in forward! :)

Comment: Not sure what could be the issue, sorry. This is a complex command, so the first thing to suggest would be to debug every part: make sure that `REG` returns the result you expect, then see if `FIND` finds the specified term (i.e. try running it without `>NUL` to see if it displays the line being searched. Next, try using `ECHO` both after `&&` and after `||` instead of `shutdown` and whatever other command(s) you intended.

Comment: UAC in my system is disabled, and after I ran this: `REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v EnableLUA | FIND "0x1" >NUL && ( ECHO OK ) || (shutdown -t 30 -r -f)`, I received a notification that a reboot was planned in less than a minute, meaning it worked as expected. I can't test it with `-t 0` at the moment, so can't be sure if there's any limitation running `shutdown -t 0` in a compound command like above.

Comment: Awesome, got it working this time, thank you so much! :)
By the way, how to go about inserting longer snippets of code inside the ( )? Right now I just used the 'call' feature to run another .bat file. But is it possible to enter longer code inside those ( )? I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well :D Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I think you are talking about inserting more commands between the brackets (or *parentheses*). And if my guess is correct then the answer is "yes, you *can* do that". That's why I wrote `command(s)` in my template, meaning it could be either a single command or multiple commands. But if my guess was wrong, kindly let me know what you meant actually.

Comment: I think we're on the same page :D I meant that the code I want to insert has multiple brackets and so I just get "The syntax of the command is incorrect" when I add it in the main ( )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13278/discussion-between-andriy-m-and-perulo)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Microsoft documentation about `EnableLUA` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/958053ae-5397-4f96-977f-b7700ee461ec):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA') do if "%%a" equ "0x0" (
rem When UAC is disabled
) ELSE (
rem When UAC is enabled
)
```